# Exchange Management Powershell - How can I get the value of the Name property here?

Tags: .net, powershell

How can I get the return value of only the Name Variable?

RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create(); 
PSSnapInException snapInException = null; 
PSSnapInInfo info = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out snapInException);
Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig); myRunSpace.Open();

//Create pipeline and feed it the script text
Pipeline pipeline = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline();

string strScript = "Get-MailboxDatabase";

//Add the command to the Commands collection of the pipeline.
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(strScript)

Collection results = pipeline.Invoke();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this. Alter your script:

```
string strScript = "Get-MailboxDatabase | select -expand name"
```

with this, `results[0].BaseObject` will be a plain string. Or you can retrieve the Name property from the PSObject wrapping the mailbox database instance:

```
string name = results[0].Properties["Name"].Value
```

or you can grab it from the mailboxdatabase Type (sorry, I don't know what that actually is) by casting `results[0].BaseObject` to this Type and accessing the property in a strongly-typed fashion.

-Oisin